# Need help asap!!! Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

How do I find the probability of someone having 65 dollars or more with a mean value of 50 dollars and a std deviation of 2 dollars.

What equation would I use to find the z-value?

Comment: Please read the rule about posting homework questions to the board and then revise your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I will not do your homework, but I will help you with the methodology.

When dealing with a normal distribution, it is often convenient to convert values into z-scores, which have a standardized distribution. You can look up a probability table for z-scores.
For any given value:
$$z_i = \frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}$$

Additionally, if you want to find the probability of a range of z-scores, you are looking to compute the area under the probability density function from the minimum score you want to the max you want.

The area under the whole curve is 1, so $1-P(x)$ where $x$ is the minimum value acceptable is the area you seek. It's up to you to apply. Also, you really should get in the habit of researching your question and problem. It is an extremely helpful skill.